# mongodb $lookup behavior when localField is not exsist

Tags: mongodb

I need help understand something.

I have got this query:

```
db.getCollection('logs').aggregate([{ 
   $match: { 
      $or: [
        { user : 1 },
        { user: 2 }
      ] 
}}, { 
    "$lookup": { 
        "from": 'users', 
        "localField": 'user', 
        "foreignField": 'user_id', 
        "as": 'user_data' 
    } 
}, { 
    "$lookup": { 
        "from": 'roll', 
        "localField": 'user_rol', 
        "foreignField": 'user_id', 
        "as": 'roll' 
    } 
}, { 
     $skip: 0 
}]);
```

and I have 3 collections,

```
logs
roll
users
```

Now, I have 2 kinds of log

**User log**

```
{
"type" : "user_log",
"user" : 1
}
```

and **roll log**

```
{
"type" : "roll_log",
"user" : 1,
"user_rol" : 1
}
```

when I query everything works fine.

I need to understand if I am performing the second `$lookup` on `user_log`, will it try to find the document, because the `localField`   does not exist on the `user_log` document.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the [`docs`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match),

> If an input document does not contain the localField, the $lookup
>   treats the field as having a value of null for matching purposes.

So the output will contain the empty array. In your case roll will be empty array.

Comment: i uderstand this but i dont undertand if it wil be perform the search

Comment: What search are you referring to ? Are you using if it joins with null value ?

Comment: i referring to the second $lookup when it wil serach the "type" : "user_log"

Comment: i just wont to preform the $lookup only when the localField is exsit on the doc

Comment: No there is no conditional look up based on type. `$lookup` doesn't take expression just local field as string. You can join them and you can clean the output so you remove the empty fields.

Comment: so if i have about 5 type of logs with 5 collection i Should not use aggregate right? becuse it wil query all the $lookup on the pipline and decreas my performance overall, i need to make query base on the type of the log

Comment: well it depends what you are trying to do. lookup can use the index for equality matches. You have to test it out for your data. If you don't need all information at once for different types then you can run separate query for each type.